# Combinations problem help

Tags: combinatorics

Four couples have reserved seats in a row for a concert. In how many different ways can they be seated if the two members of each couple wish to sit together?

At first I thought that this was 8!/4!*4! but then I was told by a teacher that this was wrong. I really don't understand the logic behind this problem, can someone lead me through? Why can't we use distinguish-ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think of each couple as a single entity: you can arrange the $4$ couples in $4!$ different orders along the row. Then the members of each couple can sit in either of $2$ orders, so there are altogether $4!\cdot 2^4$ ways to seat the couples.

Your figure of $\frac{8!}{4!}\cdot 4!$ reduces to $8!$, which is the number of ways to seat the $8$ people in the row without any restrictions on who sits next to whom. Since that includes, for instance, the arrangements in which the husbands sit in the first $4$ seats and the wives in the last $4$ seats, it cannot be right: you don’t want to count any of those arrangements.

Comment: I think both of you guys are saying that I should think of it in terms of (# of ways that 4 couples can be arranged)*(# of ways that within that couple the genders can be arranged). I never really thought of it that way. I still don't see why distinguish-ability applies so that part I'm confused

Comment: @Person: Yes, that’s exactly how we’re both analyzing it. It’s the easiest way to ensure that you count all of the acceptable arrangements and none of the unacceptable ones. Distinguishability of what? It’s the fact that the $4$ couples are distinguishable that gives us the factor of $4!$; if they were indistinguishable, we couldn’t tell one arrangement of them from another, so in effect there would be only one.

Comment: I was wondering if there is another valid approach. Say for instance you have four couples A, B, C and D. To switch a couple with its reverse pairing arrangement I would get (4 choose 1). To switch two couples, that's (4 choose 2), to switch 3 couples that's (4 choose 3) and to switch 4 couples that's (4 choose 4) so I would get 4!((4 C 0) + (4 C 1)+(4 C2)+(4 C3) + (4C4))

Comment: @Person: Yes, it’s just a bit more roundabout. $$\binom40+\binom41+\binom42+\binom43+\binom44=2^4\;:$$ you’re just counting the subsets of a $4$-element set according to their sizes instead of all at once.

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I have to finish my lunch. You guys are the best teachers :-)

Comment: @Person: You’re welcome, and thank *you*!

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about the problem is that you have four couples $A,B,C,D$, thus $4!$ ways to arrange them in a row. We then have two different orderings for each couple, so $2^4$ arrangements hence $2^4 \cdot 4!$ different seating arrangements.